# Gitlab CI: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /opt/java/openjdk when building the Docker image

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab CI file to build and push the Docker image to our container registry, here is the job I want to run inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
vcrawler-finance-docker-build:
  stage: build image
  only:
    refs:
      - main
    changes:
      - cicd/vcrawler/finance_control
  variables:
    SERVICE_NAME: 'vcrawler'
    FILE_CONTROL_NAME: 'finance_control'
    DOCKER_FILE: 'Dockerfile_finance'
  script:
    - sh cicd/build_crawler.sh
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv:
        - vcrawler/build_vcrawler.env
```

The `cicd/build_crawler` script basically executes this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 gradle:jdk17 as builder
WORKDIR /home/gradle
COPY ./build.gradle .
COPY . /home/gradle
COPY ./persistence ./persistence
RUN gradle build -x test
...
```

I get the error on the 6th line when I run my scripts on Gitlab Runner:

```bash
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /opt/java/openjdk
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

However, I don't know whether it's related but I have another Dockerfile to run another service with Gradle image: `gradle:jdk17-alpine`; it has the exact `JAVA_HOME` location, and it works fine. Thanks for any help!